# Form validation with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, validation

I am trying to validate the form input but my validation is not working.
The string must have at least one letter or digit,
an integer should be between 0-11 and should pick at least one fruit.
But even if i dont enter any input,
it just go to the input_ok.html file.
It needs to pop-up the error window.

Here is my code:

```
function validateInput() {
    var str = myForm.inputString.value;
    var nbrStr = myForm.inputInteger.value;
    var nbr = parseInt(nbrStr);
    var fruit = myForm.fruit.value;
    if (str != "" && nbrStr != "" && fruit != "" && !isNaN(nbr) && nbr < 11) {
        return true;
    } else {
        var msg = "";
        var strError = false;
        if (str == "") {
            msg += "\nPlease enter a string with at least one letter or digit";
            strError = true;
        }
        if (nbrStr == "") {
            msg += "\nPlease enter  an integer in the range 0-11";
        } else if (isNaN(nbr)) {
            msg += "\nPlease enter an integer";
        } else if (nbr > 11) {
            msg += "\nPlease enter an integer less than 11";
        }
        if (strError) {
            myForm.inputString.focus();
        } else {
            myForm.inputInteger.focus();
        }
        alert(msg);
    }
    return false;
}
```

---

```
<body>
    <h1>Week 08, Exercise 01</h1>
    <form action="week08_01servlet" 
          method="post" 
          name="myForm" 
          onsubmit="return validateInput();">
        <p>Please enter the following information, 
        and then click the submit button.</p>
        <p class="indent">A string with at least one letter or digit
            <input type="text" name="inputString">
            <br>An integer in the range 0-11
            <input type="text" name="inputInteger">
            <br>Pick a fruit <select name="fruit">
                <option value="---">---
                <option value="apple">apple
                <option value="banana">banana
                <option value="cherry">cherry
                <option value="pear">pear
            </select></p>
        <p><input type="submit" value="Submit"></p>
        <input type="hidden" name="command" value="do_it">
    </form>
</body>
```

Comment: Make sure you validate all form input **at the server side** as well. It is possible for someone to bypass the Javascript validation.

Comment: Unless your rules for validation are especially complex, I'd recommend using a pre-build javascript validation library rather than rolling your own.  There are plenty of good ones out there (I prefer http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/ but there are plenty of other libs out there, both based on a framework such as jQuery and standalone libs).  Doing it yourself is simply causing you unnecessary work, and you've still got all your server side validation to write as well (You are remembering the server side stuff, right?)

Comment: Does work here in Chrome, also range `0-11` does, at least for me, include `11`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is clearly homework, but  I beleave every question deservers an answer. Valid xhtml5, javascript checked with jslint and compressed with ajaxmin. Enjoy.

Also, you might want to read ppks [Introduction to Forms](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/forms.html).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Week 08, Exercise 01</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Week08_01.css">
    <script>
    function validateInput(c){var f=c.inputString.value,d=c.inputInteger.value,b=parseInt(d,10),g=c.fruit.value;if(f!==""&&d!==""&&g!==""&&!isNaN(b)&&b>=0&&b<11)return true;else{var a="",e=false;if(f===""){a+="\nPlease enter a string with at least one letter or digit";e=true}if(d==="")a+="\nPlease enter  an integer in the range 0-11";else if(isNaN(b))a+="\nPlease enter an integer";else if(b<=0)a+="\nPlease enter a positive integer";else if(b>11)a+="\nPlease enter an integer less than 11";if(e)c.inputString.focus();else c.inputInteger.focus();alert(a);return false}}
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Week 08, Exercise 01</h1>
    <form action="week08_01servlet" 
        method="post" 
        name="myForm"
        onsubmit="return validateInput(this);">
        <p>Please enter the following information, 
        and then click the submit button.</p>
        <p class="indent">A string with at least one letter or digit
            <input type="text" name="inputString" />
            <br>An integer in the range 0-11
            <input type="text" name="inputInteger" />
            <br />Pick a fruit <select name="fruit">
                <option value="---">---</option>
                <option value="apple">apple</option>
                <option value="banana">banana</option>
                <option value="cherry">cherry</option>
                <option value="pear">pear</option>
            </select></p>
        <p><input type="submit" value="Submit">
        <input type="hidden" name="command" value="do_it"></p>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Generally for homework questions on Stack Overflow, instead of doing the work for them, you should give clues or lead the OP down to the correct answer. If you do provide code snippets like this, provide an explanation of how your code works. The OP learns nothing if this code was simply copied-and-pasted as a whole.

Comment: @In silico: I agree with you, but I'm quite sure any teacher will spot the contents of my script tag as higly suspisious.